# How to destroy a game object in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am having trouble trying to destroy my player. I have a script attached to my platforms, that if it collides with the player start a timer, and when the timer is done, destroy gameobject(which is the platform itself). I also want to have it so if the player happens to be on the platform by the time it runs out, the player also is destroyed. So I created a bool, but I am having trouble writing a destroy just player if bool is true.

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DestroyAddPlatform : MonoBehaviour {

    //This will be used to set the seconds
    public float timeLeft = 3f;
    bool playerOn = false;
    private float PlayerGameObject;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    //How you declare a Coroutine Function.
    IEnumerator destroyer(){
        //wait for the timeLeft in seconds.
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (timeLeft);

        //Then destroy the object this script is attached to
        Destroy (gameObject);
    }

    //A timer that will start the coroutine
    void destroyTimer(){
        //coroutine calls the destroyer function, its a function that runs independently.
        StartCoroutine ("destroyer");

        //At this point tell it to add in a new platform. 
    }

    //This function will be in accordance to a collision.
    void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D other){

        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("Player"))
            //If the object is the player, run
            destroyTimer ();//Start the destroy timer funciton.
    }
```

}

Comment: could you add the code you tried? to this post

Comment: We can't help you if you don't give us a specific problem, and the code causing that problem. Also are you sure the `unityscript` tag is relevant? The language is being phased out in favour of c#, if you really are using it, i'd suggest switching and if you're already using c# then please remove the tag :-).

Comment: I have posted my code and removed the unityscript tag

Answer (score 1):

OnCollisionEnter with the player store the player's gameobject in a variable PlayerGameObject.

OnCollisionExit with player set the

```
PlayerGameObject = null;
```

Then check when the timer is done if

```
if(PlayerGameObject != null)
{
    Destroy(PlayerGameObject);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [destroy](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) method. Simply make a script and attached to an object (who will never destroyed in game). Then assign your player object to that script and use the destroy method.

```
public  var Player : GameObject;
//call this method at desired event
    function DestroyPlayer(){
        Destroy(Player);
    }
```